# How to save JSON from Duckduckgo API

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the JSON file using [DuckDuckGo Instant Answer API](https://duckduckgo.com/api), but I get error messages blocked by CORS policy.

I've tried using getJSON from Jquery, but it gives me this error message:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '' from origin '' has been blocked by 
CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the 
requested resource.
```

I know it is blocked for security reasons, but is there any way to get the JSON file?

```
  $.getJSON("https://api.duckduckgo.com/?format=json&q=" + result, function(data) {
    console.log(data.Abstract);
    abstract = data.Abstract;
  });
```

Is there any way of getting the JSON?